# How can I tell object usage?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am trying to see where objects I create are being used in our platform. How can I look at which apps my object type is being used in and track usage of these applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find where your Object Type is being used in the Dependents section of the Object Type Overview page.
[image: object type view]
You can find usage metrics of this object, such as how many active users and how many interactions in the Usage tab. (Usage tabs are currently present in certain stacks only.
[image: Usage Tab]